# Boot Camp Windows 10 not connecting to Magic Mouse 1

Tags: bootcamp, bluetooth, mouse

A week or so ago I installed Windows 10 on my 2015 MacBook Pro Retina with Boot Camp. At the start my Magic Mouse 1 and my keyboard were already paired. Today my mouse wouldn't click for some reason so I unpaired the mouse, now the mouse won't pair. In the Windows 10 Control Panel I don't see any drivers that aren't installed. I already tried restarting my laptop and turning the mouse off and back on.

Whenever I try pairing the mouse I get an pop-up from windows saying it can't find the mouse anymore and asks me to try this again. I just finished installing all my programs, I really don't want to do that again.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you verify that the mouse is working in OS X or on another machine?

Answer (score 1):

So far, I learned from experimenting and the blogs: I have to REMOVE (not just DISCONNECT) the Bluetooth mouse in Mac OS X, before I can pair it in BootCamp Windows. Since this is not comfortable enough, I'm not fully done yet.

After another entire day of fumbling around in blogs, Apple sites and the machine itself, it seems to work.

1st of all, I have to correct myself - the mouse is an Apple Bluetooth MIGHTY Mouse (not a MAGIC one). Sorry for the wrong place - there is not much word about the Mighty in the blogs.

The machine is a late 2006 MBP15 (2,2 A1211). The Mac OS X is a Lion, the BootCamp is 4.0.4 running Windows 10. Apple doesn't support this combo. They don't provide Windows Support Software for it either (the download attempt through BootCamp Assistant fails). So I'm in fact on my own.

Having eventually learned that, I decided to UNPAIR (not REMOVE) the mouse in Mac OS X, before I switched to Windows 10. In Windows 10, I managed to pair it within the Bluetooth Preference window. However, the transition had switched the mouse OFF, so I had to switch it OFF/ON again. And, I had to toggle the Bluetooth switch in the Preference window; otherwise the radio wouldn't at all search for the mouse! I think that I even had to click the mouse - but I'm not sure about that. Anyway - the mouse worked than, and I could open the Device Manager to check the Bluetooth entries and the Mouse entries. (With the mouse, the Bluetooth entry has to have 2 extra sub-entries, while the Mouse entry has to have just one extra sub-entry.)

From there, I could switch to Mac OS X. Of course, the mouse was dead, but I could pair it after having switched it OFF/ON and clicked to make it alive.

For the return to Windows 10 I could keep it paired. Arriving in Windows 10, I had just to switch the mouse OFF/ON and click to make it work.
I'm going to test this for a while - happy that there is no need for additional drivers.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  Can you expand your answer and/or provide some citations/references?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party, I know, but having just encountered this problem myself, and solving it using Mike6's convoluted answer, figured I would describe it to you in layman's terms.

If you are having difficulty connecting your Apple mouse to your MAC OS X with Bootcamp Windows 10 installed:

1. Remove the device from your MAC OS X's paired devices. This does not mean just Disconnect the device, go into the Bluetooth preferences and REMOVE the device from your list of paired devices (click on the "x" next to the device in that screen and UNPAIR your device).
2. Make sure your device is turned On.
3. Load up Bootcamp. Navigate over to your Bluetooth Devices and "Add Bluetooth or other device". Select "Bluetooth" from the box that pops open. Select your device. The device should now connect.

*Side note: Your mouse may have a more generic name, such as "Mouse", when searching for it in Bootcamp's Bluetooth Devices (after you've removed it from MAC OS X's paired devices), this is still your mouse, select it and connect.

Answer (score 0):

You would think the pairing on macOS wouldn't have anything to do with the pairing in Windows 10 since they are two different OSs on different partitions, but this is not true. I guess it has to do with how the Mac pairs with the bluetooth mouse on a hardware level.

Solution is to:

1. Go to macOS's Settings and Bluetooth Options
2. Remove Magic Mouse by clicking the x button
3. Reboot into Bootcamp
4. You should now be able to pair it on Windows.
5. When you go back to MacOS it will ask you to reconnect to the Magic Mouse and you won't lose it again on the Windows

This works for Late 2016 Macbook Pro Retina with Touchbar, Mac OS High Sierra, Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators Update)